# Suppress 'p.' for pages if `journal = {JINST}`

Tags: biblatex

The Journal of Instrumentation (JINST) usually has page numbers that start with letters. For some reason, if the first letter is 'C', `biblatex` prints 'p. ' before the page number, but not for other letters. For consistency, I'd like to suppress 'p. ' before any page number for JINST. I'd still like to keep the 'p. ' for other journals, which usually only have numbers for pages.

Below is an example demonstrating the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  useprefix=true,
  backref=true,
  backrefstyle=three,
  style=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{C03024,
  author = {zur Nedden, M.},
  title = {The LHC Run 2 ATLAS trigger system: design, performance and plans},
  journal = {JINST},
  year = {2017},
  month = {mar},
  volume = {12},
  number = {03},
  pages = {C03024},
  doi = {10.1088/1748-0221/12/03/C03024},
}
@article{P09015,
  author = {{ATLAS Collaboration}},
  title = {Performance of the ATLAS muon triggers in Run 2},
  journal = {JINST},
  year = {2020},
  month = {sep},
  volume = {15},
  number = {09},
  pages = {P09015},
  doi = {10.1088/1748-0221/15/09/P09015},
}
@article{S08003,
  author = {{ATLAS Collaboration}},
  title = {The ATLAS Experiment at the CERN Large Hadron Collider},
  journal = {JINST},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {3},
  number = {08},
  pages = {S08003},
  doi = {10.1088/1748-0221/3/08/S08003},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

C03024~\cite{C03024}

P09015~\cite{P09015}

S08003~\cite{S08003}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

This yields

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C03024` is recognised as a normal page number, because `biblatex` allows both Roman and Arabic numerals (even 'combined' like this).

For pages that aren't real pages you can use the `eid` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  useprefix=true,
  backref=true,
  backrefstyle=three,
  style=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{C03024,
  author  = {zur Nedden, M.},
  title   = {The {LHC Run~2 ATLAS} trigger system: design, performance and plans},
  journal = {JINST},
  year    = {2017},
  month   = mar,
  volume  = {12},
  number  = {03},
  eid     = {C03024},
  doi     = {10.1088/1748-0221/12/03/C03024},
}
@article{P09015,
  author  = {{ATLAS Collaboration}},
  title   = {Performance of the {ATLAS} muon triggers in {Run~2}},
  journal = {JINST},
  year    = {2020},
  month   = sep,
  volume  = {15},
  number  = {09},
  eid     = {P09015},
  doi     = {10.1088/1748-0221/15/09/P09015},
}
@article{S08003,
  author  = {{ATLAS Collaboration}},
  title   = {The {ATLAS} Experiment at the {CERN} Large Hadron Collider},
  journal = {JINST},
  year    = {2008},
  volume  = {3},
  number  = {08},
  eid     = {S08003},
  doi     = {10.1088/1748-0221/3/08/S08003},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
C03024~\autocite{C03024}

P09015~\autocite{P09015}

S08003~\autocite{S08003}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: M. zur Nedden. “The LHC Run 2 ATLAS trigger system: design, performance and plans”. In: JINST 12.03, C03024 (Mar. 2017). doi: 10.1088/1748-0221/12/03/C03024 (cit. on p. 1).]

If you don't want to change your `.bib` file, you can have Biber map the fields for you with

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle,
            match=\regexp{\AJINST\Z}, final] 
      \step[fieldsource=pages, fieldtarget=eid]
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you prefer the `pages` field and its position you can use the `bookpagination` field to tell `biblatex` to stop trying to put the "p."/"pp." prefix before the page numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  useprefix=true,
  backref=true,
  backrefstyle=three,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{C03024,
  author         = {zur Nedden, M.},
  title          = {The {LHC Run~2 ATLAS} trigger system: design, performance and plans},
  journal        = {JINST},
  year           = {2017},
  month          = mar,
  volume         = {12},
  number         = {03},
  pages          = {C03024},
  bookpagination = {none},
  doi            = {10.1088/1748-0221/12/03/C03024},
}
@article{P09015,
  author         = {{ATLAS Collaboration}},
  title          = {Performance of the {ATLAS} muon triggers in {Run~2}},
  journal        = {JINST},
  year           = {2020},
  month          = sep,
  volume         = {15},
  number         = {09},
  pages          = {P09015},
  bookpagination = {none},
  doi            = {10.1088/1748-0221/15/09/P09015},
}
@article{S08003,
  author         = {{ATLAS Collaboration}},
  title          = {The {ATLAS} Experiment at the {CERN} Large Hadron Collider},
  journal        = {JINST},
  year           = {2008},
  volume         = {3},
  number         = {08},
  pages          = {S08003},
  bookpagination = {none},
  doi            = {10.1088/1748-0221/3/08/S08003},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
C03024~\autocite{C03024}

P09015~\autocite{P09015}

S08003~\autocite{S08003}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: M. zur Nedden. “The LHC Run 2 ATLAS trigger system: design, performance and plans”. In: JINST 12.03 (Mar. 2017), C03024. doi: 10.1088/1748-0221/12/03/C03024 (cit. on p. 1).]

again this can be automated

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle,
            match=\regexp{\AJINST\Z}, final] 
      \step[fieldset=bookpagination, fieldvalue=none]
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you want Roman numerals to fail `biblatex`'s if number check, you can redefine the internal command `\blx@hook@ifnum` (note that there is no guarantee that this won't break in future versions, since we are messing with internal commands)

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@hook@ifnum{%
  \def\do##1{\uccode`##1=`\%}%
  \do\ \do\0\do\1\do\2\do\3\do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9%
  \blx@donumchars
  \let\RN\@firstofone
  \let\Rn\@firstofone}
\makeatother
```

Comment: That's a possible solution, but unlike `pages`, `eid` is printed before the date. I'd like to keep these numbers after the date. Is there a way to turn off the recognition of Roman numerals?

Comment: @SU3 See the edit for a few alternative approaches, please.

Comment: I went with the automated `bookpagination` solution.